# Detect german dialect in a string c++

Tags: c++

I need to parse each character in a string for example:

```
"foo123 aaa [ ßü+öä"
```

And leave only a-z A-Z 0-9 whitespaces and **german dialect characters**.
In this example the result would be:

```
"foo123 aaa  ßüöä"
```

The string should be parsed one character at a time since I need to know if any of the characters is from german dialect.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    std::string s = "Abc123ü + ßöÄ;";
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(),s.end(),
    [&](unsigned char c) {
        if ((c >= 'a' and c<='z') or (c>='0' and c<='9') or (c>='A' and c<='Z')) return false;
        if (c==0xDF) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }), s.end());
    
    std::cout<<"Stripped string: " << s;

    return 0;
}
```

The output here is Abc123 and I expect Abc123ß

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use regex\_replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57645454/how-to-use-regex-replace)

Comment: That's what regex is doing internally. It builds a giant state machine.
It's just a pointer in the right direction. You just reed to remove (replace by empty string) all the characters you don't want. i.e. invert the range of characters you do want. But hey, if you want to build everything yourself: be my guest. But don't come here asking us to do it for you, because Stack overflow is not a code writing service. Speaking of which: what is your actual question?

Comment: Please show a [mre] of what you've tried and what problems you're having with it. How are your strings encoded?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just test the character values directly instead of relying on locales and such. You know the encoding of the string, you know the code points you want to keep. Just write a function to test a character.

Comment: @TizSerim Strictly speaking there are no German characters in ASCII. ASCII stops at code point 127.

Comment: @TizSerim The problem with `c=='ß'` is that it varies depending on which encoding your source file uses. Just write `c==0xDF` or `c==0xE1` or whatever it is that you want.

Comment: You could filter out every `char` where `(c & 0x80) != 0`. This would cover extended ASCIIs as well as characters which form UTF-8 sequences (if all what's known is that you have an 8 bit encoding). `äöüß` are either or (depending on encoding).

Comment: @TizSerim Well that simply means that `0xDF` is not the encoding of `'ß'` in your string. Did you try `0xE1`? Or simply look at your string in the debugger. Or try `cout << hex << (unsigned)(unsigned char)c:` to find out what the encoding really is.

Comment: +1 on on what TizSerim says. It's not a good idea to have unicode characters hardcoded into a source file. Editors and revision control systems can corrupt this easily. Use the `\xNN` escape sequences to insert UTF-8 chars directly.  Also be aware of how runtime locale can influence what gets shown.

Comment: The correct encoding of `ß` is `\xC3\x9F` for UTF-8.  Which is what I'm assuming is what you want for a std::string.  You'd use `\u00DF` for a 16-bit char string.

Comment: There is still no actual focused question in your statement. "I need to" is not a question.

Comment: Anyhow, have you tried looking at `std::string s = "Abc123ü + ßöÄ;";` char by char? It's not what you expect it to be. Just print `s.length()` and be amazed...

Comment: @TizSerim Only if you know the encoding, which at the moment I'm not sure you do. It could be UTF-8, in which case your characters will be 1 to 4 bytes big.

Comment: Almost always these type of questions come down to 'Do you know the encoding of your input?', and almost always the answer is no. So the actual question cannot be answered until the encoding question is answered.

Comment: 'Since we use ASCII' misled me into thinking that you knew the encoding, but I guess you really meant 'since we use 8 bit characters' which is a completely different statement.

Comment: @TizSerim Am I missing something?  Why didn't you use `std::isalpha()` and `std::isdigit()`?  Those functions know exactly what is an alphabetic and digit characters, given the locale.  Just the mere fact of you determining the English characters by using `(c >= 'a' and c<='z')` is flawed.

Comment: @selbie: In all fairness, it's 2022. Modern IDE's are entirely capable of handling non-English characters. And git isn't breaking on them either. The main point is to use any superset of ASCII, whether ISO-8859-* or UTF-8.

Comment: @MSalters - I'd like to believe in that world. But from personal experience on an engineering team of 50+ people, someone will eventually break an encoding assumption on an existing file.

Answer (score 2):

Original ASCII is seven bit (0-127) ... 8-bit ASCII used code pages to cover other languages in (128-255)

The usual code page for German is defined in ISO/IEC 8859-1 (often also called Latin1 amongst others). Often ISO/IEC 8859-15 is actually used, because this contains the € sign, which is missing in ISO/IEC 8859-1, but for the "Umlauts", you need: äöüÄÖÜ and ß, the codes should be the same.

```
// Latin1                Ä    Ö    Ü    ä    ö    ü    ß
vector<int> ascii_vals {196, 214, 220, 228, 246, 252, 223};
```

Unfortunately, Windows likes to use code page 437 or 850, where the codes would be different again.

However, you really should use UTF-8 in modern applications. I guess you have to connect to a legacy system, when you have to use ASCII. Better define to use UTF-8 internally and convert the strings. When you send the ASCII string to a different system, that expects UTF-8 your nicely filtered German Umlauts might get converted falsely again.